# Scrapy: Spider error processing in windows 7

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I'm trying to build a spider so I can crawl and scrape content from other websites I did the example from scrapy and everything worked fine, however when implementing my own code I wasn't able to make it work. I keep getting the following error:

```
2016-02-02 17:57:15 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.andina.com.pe/agencia/seccion-clic-35.aspx/> (referer: None)
2016-02-02 17:57:15 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.andina.com.pe/agencia/seccion-clic-35.aspx/> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 28, in process_spider_output
   for x in result:
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 54, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\iaguilar\Desktop\scrap\andina\andinanews\andinanews\spiders\andina_spider.py", line 15, in parse yield scrapy.Requests(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Requests'
2016-02-02 17:57:15 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-02-02 17:57:15 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 244,
     'downloader/request_count': 1,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 247210,
     'downloader/response_count': 1,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 2, 22, 57, 15, 929000),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
     'log_count/ERROR': 1,
     'log_count/INFO': 7,
     'response_received_count': 1,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
     'spider_exceptions/AttributeError': 1,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 2, 22, 57, 10, 504000)}
2016-02-02 17:57:15 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

And this is my spider:

```
import scrapy

from andinanews.items import AndinanewsItem

class AndinaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "andina"
allowed_domains = ["andina.com.pe"]
start_urls = [
    "http://www.andina.com.pe/agencia/seccion-clic-35.aspx/"
]

def parse(self, response):
    for href in response.css("article.seccion5 > h3 > a::attr('href')"):
        url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        yield scrapy.Requests(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//section[class=cuerpo_cont]'):
        item = AndinanewsItem()
        item['title'] = sel.xpath('h1/text()').extract()
        item['image'] = sel.xpath('article[class=fotoportada]/img/@src').extract()
        item['desc'] = sel.xpath('//section[class=cuerpo_cont]/section/text()').extract()
        yield item
```

I've been at this the whole afternoon and can't find what the error is. I'm also really new at Python. If you could point me in the right direction would be great!

Comment: In your current working directory do you by chance have a file called `scrapy.py`? If so you'll need to rename it and delete `scrapy.pyc`.

Comment: @bernie nope :( I have scrapy.cfg though

Comment: Use `scrapy.Request` (singular) instead of `scrapy.Requests` (plural)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module `scrapy` does not have `Requests`. As paul trmbrth mentions in his comment: [`Request`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request) is singular anyway and is located in the `scrapy.http` module

I use most of the time

```
from scrapy.http import Request
```

so you can

```
yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)
```

without writing the whole module name every time.

Comment: actually, from Scrapy 1.0, you can use the `scrapy.Request` shortcut